# ResultSet with 4162 rows only iterates through first row

Tags: java, sql, resultset

The ResultSet videoFilenames should have 4162 rows (I tested the query in the database) but the while loop 'while (videoFilenames.next())' only iterates once - after the first filename in the ResultSet, the while loop just ends! Can anyone help me figure out why?

```
/*
 * Run: java -cp .:ojdbc6.jar FindVideosWithoutTranscodes
 */

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class FindVideosWithoutTranscodes {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //connect to database
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        String serverName = "***.***.***.***";
        String portNumber = "****";
        String sid = "*****";
        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + serverName + ":" + portNumber + ":" + sid;
        String username = "*****";
        String password = "*****";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

        //create output file
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("mp2_files_without_transcodes.txt"));

        //get ResultSet of mp2 filenames
        ResultSet videoFilenames = stmt.executeQuery("select filename from archivefile where filename like '%.mp2'");

        System.out.println("Making list of mp2 files without transcodes...");

        //for each mp2 file
        String filename;
        ResultSet smallTranscode;
        ResultSet largeTranscode;
        while (videoFilenames.next()) {
            filename = videoFilenames.getString(1);

            //check for -700.mov file
            System.out.println(filename.substring(0, filename.length() - 4) + "-700.mov"); //test
            smallTranscode = stmt.executeQuery("select * from archivefile where filename='" + filename.substring(0, filename.length() - 4) + "-700.mov'");
            if (!smallTranscode.next())
                out.write(filename + "\n");
            else {
                //check for -6500.mov file
                System.out.println(filename.substring(0, filename.length() - 4) + "-6500.mov"); //test
                largeTranscode = stmt.executeQuery("select * from archivefile where filename='" + filename.substring(0, filename.length() - 4) + "-6500.mov'");
                if (!largeTranscode.next())
                    out.write(filename + "\n");
                largeTranscode.close();
            }
            smallTranscode.close();
        }

        System.out.println("Done.");

        out.close();
        videoFilenames.close();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> only one ResultSet object per Statement object can be open at the same
>   time

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html

So once you execute your second query inside your while loop using the same Statement instance you are closing your videoFilenames ResultSet.

Answer (score 2):

The [Java Statement documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) says;

> By default, only one ResultSet object per Statement object can be open
>   at the same time. Therefore, if the reading of one ResultSet object is
>   interleaved with the reading of another, each must have been generated
>   by different Statement objects. All execution methods in the Statement
>   interface implicitly close a statment's current ResultSet object if an
>   open one exists.

In other words, you can't loop through one ResultSet and create another using the same `stmt` object, that will close the first ResultSet and end the loop.